# Why do I keep getting a routing error when running my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I keep getting a routing error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661569/why-do-i-keep-getting-a-routing-error)

Sorry Im asking this again but I didnt get any responses the first time.

I am trying to add comments to the microposts found in https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed from the michael hartl railstutorial

Here is the area in question on my routes.rb file.

```
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy] do
    resources :comments, 
  end
```

This is the error I get when I try to visit a users page: No route matches {:controller=>"comments", :format=>nil, :micropost_id=>#}

here is the output of rake routes | grep comments:

```
         user_comments GET    /users/:user_id/comments(.:format)                    comments#index
                       POST   /users/:user_id/comments(.:format)                    comments#create
      new_user_comment GET    /users/:user_id/comments/new(.:format)                comments#new
     edit_user_comment GET    /users/:user_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)           comments#edit
          user_comment GET    /users/:user_id/comments/:id(.:format)                comments#show
                       PUT    /users/:user_id/comments/:id(.:format)                comments#update
                       DELETE /users/:user_id/comments/:id(.:format)                comments#destroy
    micropost_comments GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                       POST   /microposts/:micropost_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                       PUT    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                       DELETE /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

and finally here is my comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id]) 
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment]) 
    @comment.user = current_user

    if @comment.save 
      redirect_to @micropost
    else 
      redirect_to @micropost
    end 
  end 

  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new 

  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: What url are you trying to visit that causes the error? It *should* look something like `http://foo.com/microposts/<micropost_id>/comments`

Comment: Please share the url that generates the error.

Comment: Also do you have a comments controller?

Comment: Also, please can you share the output of `rake routes | grep comments`

Comment: http://localhost:3000/users/1

Comment: I see -- here's a question: If you enter the url `localhost:3000/users/1`, can you find the line from `rake routes` that you hit? That will be the first question to ask.

Comment: well no. I can find /users/:user_id/comments. Should rake routes be listing users/1 for me? how can I get it to. I created this user before i added alot of the comment coding, if that makes a difference

Comment: If you don't get any responses to a question, you have to improve that question. Not open a new one.

Comment: but this was the same question word for word. and it got lots of responses?

Comment: Well, when you edit the original question a little bit, it will jump to the top and you will get answers. This one will be closed soon, because it's a duplicate and no one will be able to answer anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The routes generated by your routing code are:

```
GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments
POST   /microposts/:micropost_id/comments
GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/new
GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id/edit
GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id
PUT    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id
DELETE /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id
POST   /microposts
DELETE /microposts/:id
```

So to get to your comments controller, you need to post to the url  `/microposts/:micropost_id/comments` from a form -- where `:micropost_id` is the id number of the micropost you want to add the comment to.

Can you confirm the url you are posting to and what you're hoping it will do?

Comment: it is http://localhost:3000/users/1. I am hoping that it will show the users profile page with a list of microposts and the associated comments. It works for the code in the github link in the question except for the comments which I am trying to add